# c - leaking memory with binary search tree insertion

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have used Valgrind and cannot determine where my code is leaking memory in the insert() and buildName() functions. Valgrind says it's these functions but I can't pinpoint exactly where. I am very new to the concept of leaking memory with code. Help anyone? Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* Node of tree */
typedef struct Node {
    int order;
    char value;
    struct Node * left;
    struct Node * right;
} Node;

Node * insert(Node * node, char value, int order){
    if(node == NULL){
        / * free(node); */
        node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node->value = value;
        node->order = order;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        return node;
    }
    if(order > node->order){
        node->right = insert(node->right, value, order);
    }
    else if(order < node->order){
        node->left = insert(node->left, value, order);
    }
  return node;
}

char * buildName(const char * old, const char * newpart) {
    char * dot;
    char * buf = NULL;

    dot = strrchr(old, '.');
    if (dot) {
        size_t len;
        len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.*s%s.%s",
                  (int)(dot - old) + 1, old, newpart, dot + 1);
        buf = malloc(len + 1);
        if (buf) {
        snprintf(buf, len + 1, "%.*s%s.%s",
                (int)(dot - old) + 1, old, newpart, dot + 1);
        }
    }
    return buf;
}

void decode(Node * root, Node * origRoot, char * bitString, char * filename) {
    FILE * fp;
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    if (fp) {
        while(bitString[i] != '2'){
            if(bitString[i] == '0'){
                if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
                    root = origRoot;
                    i--;
                }
                else root = root->left;             
            }
            else if(bitString[i] == '1'){       
                if(root->right == NULL && root->left == NULL) {
                    root = origRoot;
                    i--;
                }
                else root = root->right;                     
            }
            if(root->value != -1){
                fputc(root->value, fp);
                printf("%c", root->value);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    FILE * fp;
    Node * root = NULL;
    char bitString[256];
    char * filename;
    int numNodes;
    int value;
    int order;
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2) {
        printf("No file specified or too many arguments. Exiting...\n");
        exit(1);
    } 

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(!fp){
        printf("Cound not open command file: %s", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    if(fp){
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &numNodes);

        while(i < numNodes){
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &value);   
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &order);
            root = insert(root, value, order);
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;
        while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
            bitString[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    filename = buildName(argv[1], "decoded");

    decode(root, root, bitString, filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Added empty:

```
void empty(Node * node) {
  node = NULL;
  if(node != NULL){
    Node * left = node->left;
    Node * right = node->right;
    free(node);
    if (left)
        empty(left);
    if (right)
        empty(right);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a pastebin link to the valgrind report? If you compiled your program with debug symbols, valgrind should give you the line number where the leaked memory was allocated.

Comment: Memory that was allocated at the end of the program has not been released. In the sense that it?

Comment: "Leaking" means not calling free() to dispose of memory that was malloc()ed during runtime before exiting the program.  As you do not have a destroy_tree() function to walk your tree and free the memory you malloc()ed, you have leaked ALL memory that was allocated by calling malloc() in insert().


Similarly, in buildName you malloc() and return a buffer, which you never free() after use so that memory is leaked as well when main() exits.

Comment: @JohnH Not that I know much, but wouldn't it be more accurate define a memory leak as *the state in which you have an allocated memory that you do not have a pointer that points to it*?

Comment: Valgrind's memory leak checker looks for all memory allocated, but not freed, when main exits.  At that point in time, when `main()` exits, you do have allocated memory where no pointers point to it, as `main()` is now out of scope, and `filename` no longer points to the memory allocated for it, etc.

Comment: @JohnH I did not malloc() in buildName()... what specifically are you referring to? Also... this isn't a search tree, I'm sorry for that. It's just a tree that doesn't need clearing. My mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't understand HOW it can be fixed?

Comment: in buildName, if(dot) you end up doing `buf = malloc(len + 1);` and then returning that allocated memory to the caller.

After using the name in decode(), your next line should be `free(filename)` - since you didn't you are letting allocated memory drop out of scope without a free() and valgrind tells you.  `main()` is no different than any other function to valgrind.

Comment: Also, you say your other tree doesn't need clearing-- and so you are letting it leak on purpose.  There is not necessarily anything wrong with that, but valgrind will always report it as a leak, because valgrind does not differentiate between main() and any other function.  Disciplined coders always free the memory they allocate.

Comment: @JohnH So what you're saying is that the tree has to be emptied before main() ends? so that it doesn't leak? I'm sorry, I don't understand "leaking" in this sense, since I'm just beginning to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it has to be freed up by your code.  Anything you allocate but do not free is officially a leak - although it might not be a harmful one, as in your case.  As I wrote in the comment below, At the end of the program, the operating system cleans up after you, but the _code itself_ is NOT deallocating them. This is why valgrind complains. It looks for leaks _before_ the operating system handles the final cleanup of the program (otherwise, it would have nothing to analyze).

Comment: @JohnH Just a method that clears the tree should be fine? Such as what I added into the original problem above? With adding `root = NULL; empty(root);` into main() at the end?

Comment: Right... although you should delete the line `node = NULL` from `empty()`, that is a bug which would leak the whole tree.  And you should call `empty(root);root=NULL;` in that order as the order your wrote would leak `root` before emptying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an "else", in your function. What happens is when you create a new node you don't return it right away, instead you proceed to the next if. This might even result in your binary search tree not being constructed correctly. Try this:

```
Node * insert(Node * node, char value, int order){
if(node == NULL){
    / * free(node); */
    node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->value = value;
    node->order = order;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
else if(order > node->order){
    node->right = insert(node->right, value, order);
}
else if(order < node->order){
    node->left = insert(node->left, value, order);
}
return node;
}
```

Comment: There is, however, a `return node;` at the end of that first `if` block. It is a matter of style, but as it is now, one could omit that `return node;` at the end of first `if` block. Nevertheless, this change does nothing.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin you are right. I overlooked that return. Then I do not see anything else that could cause a memory leak. The string are also being dynamically allocated and at the exit of the program they will be deallocated. So, I am not sure where the memory look can possibly occur in this code..

Comment: At the end of the program, the operating system cleans up after you, but the _code itself_ is NOT deallocating them.  This is why valgrind complains.  It looks for leaks _before_ the operating system handles the final cleanup of the program (otherwise, it would have nothing to analyze).